# Resolve service IP in environment variable in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

When I pass service name in environment variable in YAML file, that service name is still string, it's not being resolved in real ip address.

Example:

```
env:
  - name: ES
    value: elasticsearch
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use it directly and it should resolve fine:

```
curl $ES
```

If you use it inside your application it should also work.

Just consider that Kubernetes uses its internal DNS and the that "elasticsearch" name should only work inside the same namespace. In fact it will resolve to:

elasticsearch`.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local.`

If your elastic **service** is running in different namespace, make sure you use `elastic.<target_namespace>`.

Comment: thanks you :)
when i describe the pod => still a string value  "elasticsearch"
this is my service:
```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
  namespace: test
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - name: transport
    port: 9300
```

Comment: That is good. Now you just need to run the pod for your application in the same namespace or send `elastic.test` in the env variable.

`$curl elastic.test` should work in any container in any namespace.